# git: inconsistent behavior when using filter to strip comments

Tags: shell, zsh, configuration, git

I am using filter to remove comments before committing config files in git:

```
$ cat .git/config
[filter "stripcomments"]
clean = "stripcomments"

$ cat .git/info/attributes 
/etc/* filter=stripcomments
```

I also have shell prompt which changes color if there are any uncommited files. This is the relevant part in my `.zshrc`:

```
[[ -n "$(git status --porcelain 2> /dev/null | tail -n1)" ]] && git_c=220 || git_c=34
```

The problem I am having is, that when I change a file by adding a comment, my filter strips the comment, and the file for gits purposes should be unchanged. I can verify that by `git diff` which shows no difference. But `git status` shows the file has changed, and consequently my shell shows yellow prompt, indicating uncommited changes.

What do I have to use to solve this problem?

## EDIT:

what is even worse, when I do `git status`, it shows me modified files. When I do `git diff` it shows no changes. And when I do `git commit`, it tells me nothing to commit.

So in other words, `git status` shows changed file but I am unable to commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git status` works as expected if you change comments without changing file size e.g. change one character, or have two one-line comments and switch them, anything that doesn't change the total length of the file nor the filtered result.

For modified (mtime) files of the same size, `git status` reads their contents, runs the filter, and compares. As long as the comment changes get filtered out, there is no change.

However, if the file size is different, `git status` does not run the filter at all, and does not even look at file contents. A change in file size alone is enough to make `git status` consider the file as changed.

Comparing file sizes instead of file contents is a common optimization. Which, in this case, works against you. And there doesn't seem to be an option to turn it off.

There is `core.checkStat = minimal` which disables almost everything *except* the filesize check. So that's a dead end. If there is any other option related to this issue, I couldn't find it.

So I don't have a proper solution to change `git status` behavior.

You might have to switch to a different command altogether (run `git diff`? or `git commit --dry-run` so it doesn't actually commit?). These tools run the filter (and then do nothing) since they actually have to look at the file contents to diff/commit the changes. Otherwise, run `git add` to update the cached filesize in git? (no commit involved)

Another (weird) option would be to force the filesize issue. For text files you can just append comments, then truncate the files to always be of the same size. So the filesize never changes and `git status` does have to check the file contents for you.

That would make `git status` work for your use case but it's hardly practical.

---

A more radical approach would be to patch `git` itself.

```
diff --git a/read-cache.c b/read-cache.c
index 35e5657877..4e087ca3f5 100644
--- a/read-cache.c
+++ b/read-cache.c
@@ -213,7 +213,7 @@ int match_stat_data(const struct stat_data *sd, struct stat *st)
 #endif

        if (sd->sd_size != (unsigned int) st->st_size)
-               changed |= DATA_CHANGED;
+               changed |= MTIME_CHANGED;

        return changed;
 }
```

This would pretend a size change is merely a time change (and then kick off the file contents comparison later on). However, this would only work for you locally and this is very risky. After all, this function is responsible for the integrity of your git repository and I can't judge if such a change is safe in any way at all.

If you do anything like this you should call it frankengit and make sure it can't modify your repository at all (at minimum, add `--no-optional-locks` to the status command).

---

Same question, asked 9 years ago:

- [Why does 'git status' ignore the .gitattributes clean filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19807979/2876682)

Git mailing list discussion:

- [git filter bug](https://lore.kernel.org/git/101027c97a9b40ce97192b1cee203b07@deshaw.com/t/#u)

Nothing came of it apparently but if you care about this feature, you should take it up with the mailing list one more time regardless. Otherwise the same issue will still be around another 9 years later. ;-)